# In Rails, how do I find records by "not equal"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application that contains a bunch of projects that are at various stages, and I need to list the completed projects, or the projects that are at various other stages. So to list the completed projects, I name a scope;

```
named_scope :current, :conditions => { :current_stage => "Completed" }
```

and use;

```
@projects = Project.current
```

in my controller.

But I how do I find all the projects at other stages? I thought it would involve != but I can't get that to work.

Any pointers very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
named_scope :incomplete, :conditions => [ 'current_stage != "Completed"' ]
```

Comment: And so it does. Wahey!

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mazonowicz You should accept this answer by clicking the tick mark if this worked for you.

Comment: What about **current_stage** is nil ? How to include these in the results?

Comment: I'd say 'current_stage IS NOT "Completed"'